# NodeJS 302 Respone Querying Kibana request.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, kibana

I am trying to query kibana to retrieve logs with the help of token received from authentication
Scenario: 1) Get a bearer token from a site by passing email and password 
2) Use the above bearer token to query kibana host _msearch with body to get the json response (POST request returns a 302 and autoforwards to the content page)

The above works in postman and when i try to emulate the same in nodejs using the request library i get the status 302 and when i set the followAllRedirects:true flag i get redirected to the login page rather than the page with the contents.

Can you let me know where i am going wrong

```
var options = {
  url: kibanaEndpoint,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'bearer token',
    'kbn-xsrf': 'reporting',
    'Content-type': 'application/x-ndjson',
  },
  body: jsonModified,
  followAllRedirects:true
}

request.post(options, function (err, response, body) {
  if (err) {
    console.dir(err)
    return
  }
  console.log(response.statusCode);
  console.log(body);   
})
```

Comment: Could You try: `'Bearer {put real token here}'` (Bearer starts from `B` not `b`)

Comment: No it does work with 'b' or 'B' its the redirects i am not able to solve.

Comment: Ok. Have You tried to do it with `postman`? Check with it then move to code.

Comment: Yes it works with postman the above implementation, I got it working now it requires the usage of jar and the cookies forwarded to the subsequent requests. Its probably due to the way in which Kibana is hosted at my org.

Comment: so do that in 2 steps: 1st request will do auth, 2nd request will use cookie jar from 1st request.